# Accessing IP address of a docker container in a custom network

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am using docker compose to start kafka and zookeeper

my docker-compose is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4
    networks:
      - pipeline

  kafka:
    image: ches/kafka
    networks:
      - pipeline
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_IP=zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    links:
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

networks:
  pipeline:
```

So this starts a container running zookeeper and starts a container running kafka server which successfully connects to zookeeper.

Additionally I can successfully create a kafka producer and a kafka consumer to communicate between each other by the following commands:

Producer:

```
docker run --rm -it --network pipeline_pipeline ches/kafka \
    kafka-console-producer.sh --topic pipeline-dev \
    --broker-list kafka:9092
```

Consumer:

```
docker run --rm --network pipeline_pipeline ches/kafka \
    kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic pipeline-dev \
    --from-beginning \
    --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
```

Now the problem I am facing is that in the config the ADVERTISED HOST on the kafka server is set to `kafka`, which prevents me from connecting to the kafka server from local.

I am using the [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) library to connect to kafka in the following way:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('pipeline-dev', bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

print 'starting to listen'
for msg in consumer:
    print msg
```

But here I get the error that Brokers are not available! That is because I have set the bootstrap servers as `localhost:9092`. Even though I have forwarded the ports, I am unable to connect to the kafka server because the advertised host name is `kafka` and not `localhost`.

Setting bootstrap servers as `kafka:9092` does not work because the code is running in local and not in the docker network.

I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Make a host entry in your `/etc/hosts` with `<kafkadockerip> kafka` and see if that make it work?

Comment: @TarunLalwani the problem with that approach is that the docker container is in the docker network, so doing `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' pipeline_kafka` gives me no IP! I am not very sure how to access a docker container's IP from outside the network

Comment: I am sorry I should have said `127.0.0.1` instead of `<kafkadockerip>` if it is your docker host machine where the python code runs. Else it would the the docker host ip

Comment: Hey man! @TarunLalwani, you solved my problem! if you want you can post your comment as an answer and I will check it as the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a host entry in your `/etc/hosts` like below

```
127.0.0.1 kafka
```

Above will work when you want to use your code on the docker host machine. If you want to use it on some other machine then you should use

```
<DockerHostIP> kafka
```

Basically you want to have the name resolved when the advertised name returns `kafka`

Comment: Super thanks a lot for that. What I had tried was to add the following in the /etc/hosts `localhost kafka`. But from your answer I realised that didn't work because localhost is a hostname which then maps to the actual IP `127.0.0.1`, so finally the hostname was not being properly resolved!